# How to start puppeteer processes as low priority?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I'm using puppeteer via the Node API on a Linux host. My use case is to create different sized screenshots of a WebGL map.

The node script is called via command line arguments, it generates a few screenshots in different sizes and then exits.

My problem is that puppeteer process slows down the webserver a lot, as they are on the same host.

How can I make sure that puppeteer processes and Chrome child processes start in lowest/idle process priority?

Here is the skeleton of my Node script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const SCREENSHOT_SIZES = ...

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({})

  for (const size of SCREENSHOT_SIZES) {
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.setViewport({
      width: size.w,
      height: size.h,
    })

    try {
      await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 60 * 1000 })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }

    await page.screenshot({
      path: ... 
    })
  }

  await browser.close()
}

run()
```

Comment: If you are able to get their PID, you could try [`os.setPriority()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_setpriority_pid_priority) introduced in [`v10.10.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V10.md#2018-09-06-version-10100-current-targos).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`browser.process().pid`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserprocess) to obtain the `pid` of the spawned browser process. Then you can use [`os.setPriority()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_setpriority_pid_priority) to set the scheduling priority for the process specified by the browser's `pid`.

**Complete Example:**

```
'use strict';

const os = require( 'os' );
const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

( async () =>
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    os.setPriority( browser.process().pid, 15 );

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto( 'https://www.example.com/' );

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure pages don't have their own separate process?